# How can I have application concurrency control + no retries via postgres locks?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

One section of my application interacts with an external, non-idempotent API. Let's call this the `sendMessage` API. I'm looking at options for implementing concurrency control for this section using postgres locking, similar to what's outlined [here](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/distributed-locking-with-postgres-advisory-locks) except I think we can use normal txns + row-level locks instead of advisory locks.

My requirements are:

1. The `sendMessage` API call should happen exactly once, barring a catastrophic failure such as a data center outage.
2. The response from the call should be stored in the database, again barring catastrophic faliure.
3. Each user is allowed to perform a single mutation (`sendMessage` API call) at a time.

Additionally, the database is running with the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, since data integrity is key to the application.

As a simplified approach, I currently to have a table of requests, e.g.,

```sql
CREATE TABLE messages (
  userId TEXT NOT NULL, 
  request_payload JSONB NOT NULL,
  response_payload JSONB,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId)
);
CREATE INDEX pending_msgs ON messages(response_payload IS NOT NULL);
```

A separate process can insert into that table when a message needs to be sent. A row processor then wakes up, acquires a lock on the row, and calls the `sendMessage` API:

````js
const txn = conn.transaction(); # `BEGIN` under the hood
const [{userId, request_payload}] = await txn.execute(```
  SELECT * FROM messages 
  WHERE response_payload IS NULL 
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED 
  LIMIT 1
```);
const response = await http.post(`/sendMessage/${userId}`, payload);
await txn.execute('UPDATE messages SET response_payload = $1 WHERE userId = $2', response, userId);
await txn.commit();
````

---

It's not clear to me from the docs whether `SELECT FOR UPDATE` can throw a `serialization_failure`. When encountering those, we normally just retry, but retrying would be Bad (tm).

My understanding is that no other query running `SELECT FOR UPDATE` on this row [can proceed concurrently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS), but it seems another process could have started without `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and could concurrently modify the `message` row we've selected, leading to a `serialization_failure` for us. In that case, we would have already sent the API call by the time we see the failure (at commit).

Specifically, I *think* that's what [this section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) is saying:

> Within a REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE transaction, however, an error will be thrown if a row to be locked has changed since the transaction started. For further discussion see Section 13.4.

But in my testing, any attempted updates to the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`'d rows will hang, not cause serialization failures.

Is what I'm doing sufficient or are there edge cases I'm not seeing? Is there a stricter locking mechanism in postgres to say "no one else can modify this row during this txn, so wait until I have exclusive access to modify the row. And if someone else is trying, fail their txn instead of mine"?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is free of race conditions. As soon as you `SELECT` a row `FOR UPDATE`, no concurrent transaction can modify that row.

However, serialization errors can still occur during the `UPDATE`. Whether you can get a serialization error or not depends on the access method chosen during the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`:

- If PostgreSQL chooses a sequential scan, the whole table will get a predicate lock indicating that all rows were read. The second `UPDATE` from two concurrent transactions will then trigger a serialization error, because both modify data that the other transaction has read.
- If PostgreSQL uses an index scan, only the scanned rows will be predicate locked as read by the transaction. In that case, you will probably away without a serialization error. It is not certain, because predicate locks on many rows can by escalated to page locks, and you can still get a conflict.

So your best strategy is to write your code so that it can repeat the transaction (it's not that hard), while at the same time creating an index that reduces the likelihood of serialization errors as much as possible:

```
CREATE INDEX ON messages ((1)) WHERE response_payload IS NULL;
```

If the table is small, or if many rows have no response payload, PostgreSQL may still prefer a sequential scan. You could prevent that by discouraging sequential scans for the duration of the transaction:

```
SET LOCAL enable_seqscan = off;
```

Two additional observations:

1. the index that you created makes no sense for your statements
2. you should use `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` instead of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, since the former is the correct lock for an `UPDATE` that does not modify a primary or unique key

Comment: Thanks for the excellent insights. I'd forgotten about page locks, the ability to set flags within a txn, and your index is what I meant -- it was late when I wrote this :) Any thoughts on how to write this code such that the API call is only made once, while supporting possible txn retries? The API doesn't support any kind of idempotency token / deduplication, and truly must not be called more than once. I need to read the row, make the call, and update the row.

Comment: What about a simple loop in the code? You only exit the loop if you get no serialization error.

Comment: The API call must not be retried, and I need to update the row with its returned value. Normally, we put a `maxRetries` loop around our txns, inspecting for `serialization_failure`, deadlocks, etc. The problem is the `http.post` (which is interleaved within the txn above) must only happen once.

Comment: I'm talking about the code on the API server side. You call the API function, and the function loops, trying the database transaction until it succeeds.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the API server is unfortunately external -- we don't control it and it doesn't support any kind of deduplication. They're also big enough that complaints from us about their poor API design will fall on deaf ears :(

Comment: Ah. Then the requirement "the API call must not be retried" is strange. Particularly since the target is a database, which rolls back every modification that fails. If it really is like that, you are out of luck. Your only option with such a brain-dead system and `SERIALIZABLE` would be to take a very high lock on the table before you attempt the operation. But this is not an option either, if the call happens frequently, because that will eventually get you in trouble with autovacuum, which can break your database.